# Plotting Graph in IronPython via IronLab

Tags: python, numpy, ironpython

I am using IronPython 2.7.1 with IronLab 1.1.2.0 so I can use numpy and IronPlot in IronPython 2.7.1
IronPython: https://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/62475
IronLab: https://code.google.com/p/ironlab/downloads/detail?name=ironlab%201.1.2.0.zip&can=2&q=

When I run the 3 getting started commands that IronLab recommends

```
import numpy as np
import ironplot as ip
ip.plot(np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)))
```

via IronPythonConsole located in the IronLab directory, they work fine.

After importing the libraries into IronPython via IronLab in the ipy IronPython console,

```
import sys, clr

sys.path = ['.', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronLab 1.1.2.0\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronLab 1.1.2.0\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronLab 1.1.2.0\\lib\\site-packages'] + sys.path

clr.AddReference("mtrand.dll")
```

the first two imports work fine, however the ip.plot command gives me MemoryError: Exception of type 'System.InsufficientMemoryException' was thrown.

After researching this exception online, I saw that it could be a problem with my system running out of physical memory. However, I have 8 GB of RAM on 64 bit Windows and I have only noticed 45% being used in Task Manager when I am running this command. Others recommended changing code so less memory would be used, but as this is one of the "starting" commands, I am uncertain what to do. Would anyone have any advice on how I could get IronPlot to work in IronPython?

Comment: Since I haven't been able to get ironplot to work through ipy, I'm running things through IronPythonConsole for now and it seems to be working.